SQLite function TimeDiff does not seem to be supported by FireDAC in Delphi
I can execute queries directly in SQLite that support the timediff, but if I use a TFDQuery it says the function is not supported.  What am I missing?
Update: An example select statement would be
SELECT timediff('now','1809-02-12');

Which if I run in HeidiSQL happily returns +0215-09-17 00:39:18.889. But if I run this in a TFDQuery (via a TFDConnection talking to a SQLite DB) I get [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: no such function: timediff.

nothing, most creepy entity frameworks, they are often behind the actual functionality of the database they are using. most entity framework supports raw query which can mitigate those problems

I might be able to use the pre-processor in FireDAC: SELECT {fn timestampdiff('YEAR', '1809-02-12', {fn NOW()}) };

Note that timediff was introduced with SQLite Release 3.43.1 on 2023-09-11. So the solution is likely to use a newer version of SQLite. Ref: https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_43_1.html

The Info tab of the FireDAC Connection Editor will have a line like Client version = 3.31.1.  That particular result is from Delphi 12.1 which is using an SQLite library too old to have timediff.

It looks like Delphi 12.2 has SQLite 3.42 statically linked, and timediff was introduced in 3.43.  I will now work out how to dynamically link sqlite3.dll

The TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink component has a property EngineLinkage to control that.

Delphi 12.2 has a slightly too old version of the SQLite DLL statically linked.  The TimeDiff function was introduced into SQLite in version 3.43. This means you need to link the DLL to your application dynamically.
First download the latest version of the DLL.  Then, in your application, drop a TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.  Set the DriverID to something (e.g. SQLite347), the EngineLinkage to slDynamic, and the VendorLib to the full path to sqlite3.dll you downloaded earlier.
Next, on your TFDConnection, set the DriverName to whatever you set the DriverID above.  If you set the properties in the IDE at design-time, opening a query with TimeDiff should work from the IDE.
Or at run-time:
uses
  FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteWrapper;

procedure TMyDataModule.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1.DriverID := 'SQLite347';
  FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1.EngineLinkage := slDynamic;
  FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1.VendorLib := 'Z:\Downloads\SQLite\sqlite3.dll';
  FDConnection1.DriverName := 'SQLite347';
end;

I've made a video demonstrating this on YouTube.
